# Displaying variables on Kivy app using Builder.load_string

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

How would i display dikt['r_pi'] on the Builder.load_string itself, and update it every time I tap on the update button?

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.fullscreen = 0
Window.size = (1000, 500)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
import json
import requests
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyApp(App):

    url = 'https://podluck-b3df6.firebaseio.com/.json'
    auth_key = '2BKTZfCSuILkpIRKzDAIWOMkhaC5jIq069Eg4oLS'

    def get(self):
        request = requests.get(self.url + '?auth=' + self.auth_key)
        dikt = request.json() #yes it IS a dict i checked
        self.btn.text = "The pod is" + str(dikt['r_pi'])
        print(dikt['r_pi'])

    def build(self):
        return KV

KV = Builder.load_string ("""

ScreenManager:
    id: manager
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                Button:
                    id: btn
            GridLayout:
                cols:1
                Button:
                    text: 'Update'
                    on_release: app.get()

""")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I am expecting the screen to display "not occupied", which is the value to the "r_pi" key on my firebase database, but I am getting the following instead:

'MyApp' object has no attribute 'btn'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is relative to the tree that belongs, that is, you have to get the ScreenManager first, and in this case it is the root so the solution is:

```py
def get(self):
    request = requests.get(self.url + '?auth=' + self.auth_key)
    dikt = request.json() #yes it IS a dict i checked
    self.root.ids.btn.text = "The pod is" + str(dikt['r_pi'])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Did not expect it to be a one liner edit!